# Ping code java not working

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I use the following code

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
// this code assumes IPv4 is used
byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
{
    ip[3] = (byte)i;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
    if (address.isReachable(1000))
    {
        System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged");
    }
    else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
    {
        System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(address + " the host address and host name " +
            "are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved");
    }
}
```

To try and find all online devices on my wifi network.
However, two problems arise.

1. All 253 tested IPs come back positive
2. My computer is the only one that has a device name, and the ip is off.

Any help solving this dilemma?

Comment: Umm, I just tried this code on my network and it worked perfectly... Do you have something forcing your ICMP packets to return true?

Comment: Actually I figured out I was getting my loopback addresses. Had to use a slightly different way to get my ip

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar code with oracle jdk 1.8.0_51 and works fine; but when i test it on oracle jre 1.8.0_91 all the ip's of the network segment come back positive.

Maybe is a Bug with InetAddress.isReachable(1000) on the current jre version, a similar bug was reported on openjdk https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145011